# How to sum a property value in an array and multiply by a constant value

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a simple  wages calculator app that accepts input {name:'',contact:'',designation:''} ,then sums up the number of {name:''}'s input. The resultant total will then be multiplied by a constant value {wages=2,500} to give a final total.

I have written the code to accept and display new inputs, and then add this new input to the existing state. but I can't figure out how, to sum up just the name properties, and then multiplied by a constant value.

```
class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state={
  wages:0,
  totalWages: 0,
  workers:[
{
  id:uuid(),
  name:'James',
  contact:'08087453758',
  Desig:'Carpenter'
},
{
  id:uuid(),
  name:'Eric',
  contact:'08145653605',
  Designation:'Carpenter'
}

    ]
}


  }
  render() {
    const{workers}=this.state;

    return (
      <Container>
    <Button

    style={{marginBottom:'2rem'}}
    color='dark'
    onClick={()=>{

      const name=prompt('Enter the name of a new worker');
      if(name){
        this.setState(state=>({ workers:[...state.workers, {id:uuid(),name}]}))
      }
    }}
    >
    Add Worker
    </Button>    
    <ListGroup>
      {workers.map(({id,name})=>(
         <CSSTransition
         key={id}
         timeout={500}
         >
           <ListGroupItem>

             {name}
           </ListGroupItem>


        </CSSTransition>
      )

      )}

      </ListGroup>   


      </Container>

    )
  }
}
```

I need the total sum of input, displayed alongside the updated state

Comment: could be better to give an example to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

To get the total number of names use the `reduce` method

```
workers.reduce((a, b) => ({names: a.name + b.name}));
```

Comment: Where is the best place to put the reduce method in the code?

Comment: I would move your `setState` out of the `render` method and have a function that when someone adds a new name calculates (using the `reduce` method) and then sets the state.